# Property 'createDecipheriv' does not exist on type 'Crypto'

Tags: typescript, cryptography

I am getting error's in my file called PasswordDecrypt.ts

**This is the Error:**

error TS2339: Property 'createDecipheriv' does not exist on type 'Crypto'.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'iv'.

**PasswordDecrypt.ts**

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
algorithm = 'sed-ded-xby',
password = new Buffer('xxxxxxxxxx', 'utf-8');
iv = new Buffer('L4i/N0z6qx9=', 'base64');

var decr = function  decrypt(text){
  var encrypted = new Buffer(text, 'base64');
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
    var decoded = decipher.update(encrypted, 'binary', 'ascii');
    decoded += decipher.final('ascii');
    return decoded;
  }
module.exports.decr = decr;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lambdats",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "LambdaTS",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp clean && gulp compile && gulp node-mods",
    "deploy": "gulp clean && gulp zip"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.4.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.0.2",
    "lambda-local": "0.0.6",
    "node-aws-lambda": "^0.1.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.44",
    "aws-lambda": "0.0.14",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.661.0",
    "aws-secrets-manager": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.3.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cheerio": "^0.19.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "guid": "0.0.12",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "mssql": "^4.0.4",
    "node-connection-string-builder": "^0.0.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta11",
    "tedious": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I believe Crypto is a built in module. Then why i am not able to use it.

Kindly help me with this.